# Decode JSON POST in php

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am using `dataType:'json'` and `data: {'post':val}` in my ajax to send the data to my php file. `val` in `data: {'post':val}` is a variable.
The data sent to the php file is `[object Object]` so, before assigning it to a php variable, I need to decode it. I am new to JSON and don't know much.
I tried `$id=$_POST['post'];` but that doesn't work since the sent data is in JSON format.
How do I send *'normal'* data or decode the data whithout removing `dataType:'json'` as my php file has an array which is sent back to ajax by `json_encode`

Note: the value is perfectly assigned when in the Ajax. (When I alert it with `alert({post:val}['post']);` the result shown is what I assigned).
Hmm .. Here is my **Updated** Ajax (I accidentally posted a wrong one in previous code):-

```
function op_prof(obj) {
    var xval = obj.id;
    var dataString = "{'u_search':'"+xval+"'}";

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/script/profile.php',
    data: dataString,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: You're looking for `json_decode` usage would be like: `$id = json_decode($json)->u_search;`.

Comment: can you add the php script profile.php ? the fact that data is an object is quite normal as jquery ajax eval json automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`dataType` specifies *The type of data that you're expecting **back** from the server.* It will not cause the data to be sent as JSON.

If the data being set to the PHP program is `[object Object]` then something is causing some object to be stringified and put in the data that is sent. You haven't shared sufficient code to determine exactly that that is.

Comment: @Tom — After the update, that code will send the string `{'u_search':xval}`, not `[object Object]`

Comment: @Quetin I have updated the code .. If I use `{'u_search':xval}` the codes in `success:` do not run

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
data: {post: dataString}
```

instead, and in php, use `json_decode($_POST['post']);`. In this way, posted data have their name('post' here), you can see it with WebKit inspector or Firebug.

If you use `data: dataString`, there won't be any data in `$_POST`, but you can still retrieve `dataString` in PHP script using `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]`, which is url encoded. So the completed line should be `$dataString = urldecode($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);`

Furthermore, if `dataString` is stringified from a simple, non-nested object, you can use

```
data: {key1: value1,
       key2: value2}
```

then retrive values in php with `$value1 = $_POST['key1'];`, saving time encoding and parsing JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're preparing your data to send as a string. There's no need for this. The `data` param expects an object of data, so give it an object. Then, on the server side, each piece of data within that object will arrive as a separate post var.

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/script/profile.php',
    data: {foo: 'bar'}, //<-- our data is an object, not a string to be decoded
    type: 'post'
}).done(function(response) {
    alert(response); //<-- alerts "received data "bar"!"
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['foo'])) echo 'received data "'.$_POST['foo'].'"!';
?>
```

As Quentin mentioned, the `dataType` param dictates the data format you expect **back** from the server, not the format you are sending **to** it.

Comment: Yes but you're still preparing your data as a JSON string. This is the problem. Prepare it instead as an object, not a string, and pass that. You should never have to craft your own JSON strings in JavaScript, or in PHP for that matter.

Comment: If I use `data:{u_search:'xval'}`, the codes on `success:` dont run

Comment: I can only repeat: prepare and pass your data to $.ajax as an OBJECT, not, as currently, as a string.